# How to pass ng-click item to http's data payload

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am unable to pass the item stored in `onSMSHeaderDetail_Click`, which is coming from `ng-click` directive to http data payload.

```
.controller('smsDCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.onSMSHeaderDetail_Click = function(item){
        console.log(item);
        $scope.threadi = $scope.item;
        // console.log(thread);
    };

    $http({
        url: "http://****",
        dataType: "json",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        data : {
             phoneId : "******",
             threadId: $scope.threadi
        }
    }).then(function (response) {

        $scope.smsDetails= response.data.body;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line `$scope.threadi = $scope.item;`

to `$scope.threadi = item;`

Answer (score 1):

You can try change

`$scope.threadi = item;` and  `$scope.smsDetails= response.data` . And put 
ajax in your ng-click

```
  $scope.onSMSHeaderDetail_Click = function(item){
        console.log(item);
        $scope.threadi = item;
        // console.log(thread);
 $http({
        url: "http://****",
        dataType: "json",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        data : {
             phoneId : "******",
             **threadId: $scope.threadi**
        }
    }).then(function (response) {

        $scope.smsDetails= response.data;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try following code**

.controller('smsDCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

```
$scope.onSMSHeaderDetail_Click = function(item){
$http({
    url: "http://****",
    dataType: "json",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    data :JSON.strigify( {
         phoneId : "******",
         threadId: item })
}).then(function (response) {
    $scope.smsDetails= response.data.body;}
```

};

Comment: thanks for the help but it didn't work as well, anyhow I have found the solution. I have created separate javascript file where I have declare some global variables, those global variable are being set in onSMSHeaderDetail_Click function and passed to http payload.

Comment: Well my solution is not a very good approach for this problem relative to angularjs, there could be much better solutions for it but still if you're saying so I am sharing it.

Answer (score 0):

javascript file

```
var ipv=" ///required ip ";
var phoneId = null;
var threadDetailId = null;
```

.controller('smsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

```
    $scope.onSMSHeaderDetail_Click = function (item) {
        console.log(item);
        threadDetailId = item;
    };
    $http({
        url: "http://"+ipv+"/getSMSHeaders",
        dataType: "json",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        data: {
            phoneId: phoneId,

        }
    }).then(function mySucces(response) {

        if(response.data.body==null ||response.data.body =="")
        {
            $scope.myErrorMsgd="No data available";
        }
        else {
            $scope.smsHeaders = response.data.body;
        }
    },function myError(response) {
             $scope.HeaderError="Error: Request failed";
});


$scope.onRefresh= function(){
    $http({
        url: "http://"+ipv+"/updateSMSHeaders",
        dataType: "json",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        data: {
            phoneId: phoneId,


        }
```